# Php Sqlite3 : insert statment works in command line but not in browser

Tags: php, sqlite, apache2

hello this is my code :

```
<?

$DBNAME='astbase.db';
$MYTABLE ='extens';

$wsdl = "wwwwww";
$reply = "wwww";
$idsms = "4";
$exten = 100;

$base= new PDO('sqlite:'.$DBNAME);//, 0666, $err);
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $MYTABLE(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,exten VARCHAR(255), wsdl TEXT, reply text, idsms INTEGER)";    
$results = $base->exec($query);
print_r($results);

$query = "INSERT INTO $MYTABLE(id,exten,wsdl,reply,idsms) VALUES(NULL,'$exten','$wsdl','$reply',$idsms)";
$results = $base->exec($query);
print_r($results);

?>
```

when i execute the script in the command line (php5 script.php), it works fine , but when i run it with the web browser, only the first statement is executed !!! what's wrong ??

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should

- check your PHP error log file
- call the `sqlite_last_error()` function just after your first statement ([manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-last-error.php))

I'm guessing it is a permissions issue, i.e. your webserver does not have the right to write in the directory where your sqlite database file is located.

It works with the command line because it uses your own user's rights (whereas in the browser it uses Apache's user, which often has less rights).

Comment: yes thanks, it's permissions problem, i set the file database to 777 but the directory didn't allow public access, i added the user www-data (apache user) to the owner group and it's working, thank you :)